# check if user likes a facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a canvas application that tries to check if user is a fan with this code:

```
$params = array(
 'method' => 'fql.query',
  'query' => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='MY_APP_ID' and uid = me()",
);

$result = $facebook->api($params);
```

The $result[0] is not set, and therefore is empty, even though I have liked the app.
Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Have you requested the [`user_likes` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/)?

Comment: As fasr as I know, user_likes permission is only required if you're doing it via javascript SDk,  not for server-side call.

Comment: So there is your mistake :) You have to request that permission no matter how you are retrieving it. What would be the use of the permissions if not?

Comment: okay let me try it, a side question:  when I update the permissions set for my app, will those users who have already granted the old permissions have to grant new permissions as well?

Comment: Most definitely. It all depends on how you implemented the request for permissions. It sounds to me like you are simply entering the permissions directly into the settings of your app on Facebook. If that is the case, I'm not 100% sure how it will behave (but it shouldn't be too hard to test it). If you are initiating the permissions dialog manually, then you'll have to test to see if the user has already granted the permission, if not you'll have to initiate the permissions dialog again.

Comment: I've granted the user_likes permission but $result[0] is still empty (isset is false). Any ideas? thanks

Comment: I've just noticed that you are specifying your `APP_ID` instead of a `PAGE_ID`. Users can not like an application in the same way that they can not "like" another user. If you have a page for your application you'll have to use that `PAGE_ID`.

Comment: That's the thing actually - I thought about PAGE_ID but I can't find it. It's not specified in my APP settings.

Comment: Please see my answer below for how you can create a page specifically for your application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there are two likely issues here -

1. You have not requested the `user_likes` permission from your users. You will need this permission to access any data on a users "likes".

   This permission is required no matter how you intend to retrieve the information, server side or client side, with or without an SDK.
2. You have specified your application's ID instead of a `PAGE_ID` in your FQL query. Users can not "like" an application in the same way that they can not "like" another user.

You can create a page for your application from within it's "App Details" page. You can navigate to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/appdetails` and scroll down to the "contact info" section. There you will see a "Create Facebook Page" button.

[image]

Once you have created an App Page, you'll be able to use it's `PAGE_ID` to let your users "like" it and then will be able to verify the like action from within your application.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it after 7 hours of struggle.

Comment: @ast - Happy to help :) Don't wait so long next time to come ask for assistance here :P